# how to make an ajax call in XUL environment

Tags: ajax, jquery, xul

in XUL environment I tried different method using JQuery such as

```
        $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.X-site.com/api/call.php?q=test',
        success: function(){alert('success');},
        error: function(req,str,e){alert(str)}

    });
```

Not getting any callback.... But the call has been made and received on the X-site. This is a X-Site call.
[Posted a similar question using jsonGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158283/trouble-using-getjson-call-with-jquery-in-a-xul-environment)

How can I make an AJAX call in XUL env., any other means than jQuery ?

Comment: [some help here](http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/make-jsonp-work-in-firefox-chrome.html) but solution is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically does not work with standard jQuery.

But the XUL documentation tells you how to do it :
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Connecting_to_Remote_Content)